# Unable to configure postgreSQL datasource for Keycloak

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jboss, keycloak

I'm trying to configure a PostgresSQL datasource by following the 
tutorial presented in the documentation: 
http://www.keycloak.org/docs/1.9/server_installation_guide/topics/database.html
.
I'm doing the configuration for a standalone server by running 
standalone.bat and by configuring everything in 
keycloak-3.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml .

I'm following the documentation step-by-step, but I get the following 
error running standalone.bat every-time, and thus I'm unable to connect to the database.

```
15:33:11,684 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add"
) failed - address: ([
 ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
 ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with 
missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
 "org.wildfly.data-source.KeycloakDS is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.postgres-driver]",
 "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.postgres-driver]"
]}
15:33:11,687 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add"
) failed - address: ([
 ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
 ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with 
missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
 "org.wildfly.data-source.KeycloakDS is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.postgres-driver]",
 "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.postgres-driver]",
 "org.wildfly.data-source.KeycloakDS is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.postgres-driver]"
```

I have tried different versions of JDBC drivers provided by: 
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/, but to no avail, even by 
using the version mentioned in the documentation.

At this point I am stuck since my configuration files look exactly like 
in the documentation. What exactly could I be missing? Is the 
documentation up to date?

you cant find the same question- http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-March/010120.html,
but couldnt find any solution there,so re posting the same here.

Answer (score 2):

I use `jboss-cli.sh` (or .bat if you're on Windows) to manage this for me.  With Keycloak stopped and your `PATH` including `$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin` I put the script below into a file (example: config_db.cli):

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml --std-out=echo

batch
#
# remove the default provided datasource
#
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS/:remove

#
# add it back using PostgreSQL
#
module add --name=org.postgres --resources=/path/to/your/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgres",driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)

/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS/:add(connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name,driver-name=postgres,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,password=db_password,user-name=db_user)

run-batch
```

And run with `bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=config_db.cli`

Note that this assumes you've already created a PostgreSQL database user (`db_user` above) with a password (`db_password`) and a database owned by the db_user (`db_name`).

In this way I can create my datasources the same way on my local machine as I do on my servers.

**CORRECTIONS MADE:** The format for running the jboss-cl.sh is:
bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=filename